# roscore failed to start

Tags: ros-fuerte, roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there. Recently I came across a problem with roscore. The only thing I can tell is the following log:

```
irobot@irobot-desktop:/opt/ros/fuerte/share/turtlesim$ roscore
... logging to /home/irobot/.ros/log/a375ca62-9fcd-11e1-9063-4025c2c905d8/roslaunch-irobot-desktop-16615.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 257, in main
    p.start()
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 257, in start
    self._start_infrastructure()
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 215, in _start_infrastructure
    self._start_server()
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 166, in _start_server
    self.server.start()
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/server.py", line 368, in start
    code, msg, val = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(self.uri).get_pid()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1224, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1575, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1264, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1289, in single_request
    self.send_request(h, handler, request_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1391, in send_request
    connection.putrequest("POST", handler, skip_accept_encoding=True)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'putrequest'
```

Bellow is a script to import system variables at start up:

```
#!/bin/sh
source /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash
source /usr/share/gazebo-1.0.0/setup.sh
export ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
export PATH=$ROS_ROOT/bin:$PATH
export PYTHONPATH=/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
export ROS_WORKSPACE=~/ros_workspace
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/ros_workspace:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
export ROS_PARALLEL_JOBS=-j4
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
export ROS_HOSTNAME=localhost
echo ROS_MASTER_URI=$ROS_MASTER_UR
```

Does anyone have any ideas what is wrong? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34191/roscore-failed-to-start/) by [Roman Burdakov](https://answers.ros.org/users/1201/roman-burdakov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2012-05-16

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-05-17**:
What OS are you on? Did you install from .debs? Have you tried with just doing "source /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash"... you shouldn't need to set the rest of those variables just to get a roscore to start (and things like ROS_ROOT, PYTHONPATH, etc should be configured by /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash)

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2012-05-20**:
You should not be doing this in a setup script.  For anybody who finds this in the future, setting some of these variables may be unsupported and break things.  You should be using ROSWS, in general.

**Comment by [Roman Burdakov](https://answers.ros.org/users/1201/roman-burdakov/) on 2012-05-21**:
I'm using Ubuntu 11.10, installed based on instructions http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu, all export are done in setup.sh file which loads from .bashrc, . How should I use rosws applied to this problem? I'm about to remove whole ROS installation and install it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you have a problem inside your xmlrpclib installation.  It's implying that connection is of NoneType which is bad.  Do you have a nonstandard version of xmlrpclib?

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0